# Upload files to Azure Storage from Azure VM using SDK azblob and Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure, go, authentication, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to upload files to azure storage container using [Go SDK for Azure storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go) from an Azure VM which has Azure Managed Identity attached to it. I am also using [Azure auth](https://github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth) to create a `ServicePrincipalToken` using `MSIConfig`. However I am receiving an error

`RESPONSE Status: 400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.`

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

Script I have used (modified form of the [example](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.12.0/azblob?utm_source=gopls#example-UploadStreamToBlockBlob) ):

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
)

func main() {
    azureServicePrincipalToken, err := auth.NewMSIConfig().ServicePrincipalToken()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    accountName := "<TESTSA>"
    containerName := "<TESTCONTAINER>"

    // Create a BlockBlobURL object to a blob in the container (we assume the container already exists).
    u, _ := url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/readme.txt", accountName, containerName))
    credential := azblob.NewTokenCredential(azureServicePrincipalToken.Token().AccessToken, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    blockBlobURL := azblob.NewBlockBlobURL(*u, azblob.NewPipeline(credential, azblob.PipelineOptions{}))

    log.Println(blockBlobURL)

    ctx := context.Background() // This example uses a never-expiring context

    // Perform UploadStreamToBlockBlob
    bufferSize := 2 * 1024 * 1024 
    maxBuffers := 3     
          
    _, err = azblob.UploadStreamToBlockBlob(ctx, strings.NewReader("Hello azblob"), blockBlobURL,
        azblob.UploadStreamToBlockBlobOptions{BufferSize: bufferSize, MaxBuffers: maxBuffers})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

When I execute `go run main.go`, I receive the following error:

```
2020/12/26 17:58:07 https://<TESTSA>.blob.core.windows.net/<TESTCONTAINER>/readme.txt
2020/12/26 17:58:07 write error: -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, /home/<MYUSER>/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.12.0/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=) =====
Description=Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
RequestId:f30c063e-901e-0046-2cb0-db4781000000
Time:2020-12-26T17:58:07.7810745Z, Details:
   Code: InvalidAuthenticationInfo
   PUT https://<TESTSA>.blob.core.windows.net/<TESTCONTAINER>/readme.txt?blockid=j%2BItsAdqRN6EScZ3S2r8QwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D&comp=block&timeout=61
   Authorization: REDACTED
   Content-Length: [12]
   User-Agent: [Azure-Storage/0.12 (go1.13.9; linux)]
   X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [21638ec4-138c-434d-4b53-d13924e51966]
   X-Ms-Version: [2019-12-12]
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   RESPONSE Status: 400 Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
   Content-Length: [298]
   Content-Type: [application/xml]
   Date: [Sat, 26 Dec 2020 17:58:07 GMT]
   Server: [Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
   X-Ms-Request-Id: [f30c063e-901e-0046-2cb0-db4781000000]


exit status 1
```

I have also verified with the `azcli` command and I was able to upload a sample txt file `helloworld` to the storage container without any challenge. The commands I used:

```sh
az login --identity
az storage blob upload --container-name <TESTCONTAINER> --account-name <TESTSA> --name helloworld --file helloworld --auth-mode login
```

Response:

```
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
{
  "etag": "\"0x8D8A9CCDD921BA7\"",
  "lastModified": "2020-12-26T18:34:22+00:00"
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you refer to authorizes with [Shared Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#specifying-the-authorization-header) and [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) API, but not Azure AD.

```
credential, err := NewSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
```

If you would like to authorize with Azure AD by `ServicePrincipalToken`, see [Azure Active Directory authentication for Go](https://github.com/Azure/go-autorest/tree/master/autorest/adal).

```
applicationSecret := "APPLICATION_SECRET"

spt, err := adal.NewServicePrincipalToken(
    *oauthConfig,
    appliationID,
    applicationSecret,
    resource,
    callbacks...)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// Acquire a new access token
err  = spt.Refresh()
if (err == nil) {
    token := spt.Token
}
```

Comment: Why is application secret needed if Managed Identity is already attached to the VM? I would like to use the MSIConfig but not the OAuthConfig. My whole purpose is to upload a file to container using MSI. Can you please let me know if it's possible?

Comment: Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-go) and replace resource with `https://storage.azure.com`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Can you please edit your answer as well? Since it is not what the title is for and it doesn't address the MSI.